# Populate JSP drop down in Filter class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jpa

I want to populate values from Database in a drop down in JSP.
The problem is, I am not forwarding a request to this JSP from any servlet. I am opening this JSP directly from the URL.

```
http://mywebsite/thisJsp.jsp
```

Now I don't want to use any Java code inside JSP and I am using EclipseLink JPA. What I did is I created a filter class.

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter{

    private FilterConfig filterConfig = null;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        String servletPath = httpRequest.getServletPath();
        if(servletPath != null & servletPath.endsWith("thisJsp.jsp")) {
            CatalogDB cdb = new CatalogDB();
            List<Catalog> catalogs = cdb.getCatalogs();
            request.setAttribute("catalogs", catalogs);
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

}
```

Now I configured this Filter in web.xml

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>MyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

The problem is flow is going inside Filter and fetching value from database. Its even setting it in request object. But on JSP I am getting an error that "catalogs" cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

I am very sorry guys, there was small error in JSP.
I was using

```
<c:forEach var="catalog" items="catalogs" >
```

instead of

```
<c:forEach var="catalog" items="${catalogs}" >
```